# C/C++ Python interpreter

Tags: c++, python, c, interpreter

What I'm trying to do is write an app in C/C++ which will allow users to enter a Python script, which the app will then interpret & run. The aforementioned script will have a separate API that I'll implement in C, then expose to the user.

Is there a way to do this? I've searched on Google, but I've only found ways to create 'extensions' and not actual interpreters (like Lua allows).

Comment: This is definitely possible. I'm not sure how, but I do know you can run a Python interpreter inside your C program. Civilization IV does it. :-)

Comment: "Binding" may be throwing off your search. Generally it indicates some kind of interface between languages, but "embedding" is what you mean.

Comment: @peachykeen thanks for heads up, maybe that's why I've had issues in the past!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Documentation about [Embedding Python in Another Application](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) says:

> The previous chapters discussed how to extend Python, that is, how to extend the functionality of Python by attaching a library of C functions to it. **It is also possible to do it the other way around: enrich your C/C++ application by embedding Python in it.** Embedding provides your application with the ability to implement some of the functionality of your application in Python rather than C or C++. This can be used for many purposes; **one example would be to allow users to tailor the application to their needs by writing some scripts in Python**. You can also use it yourself if some of the functionality can be written in Python more easily.

Look especially into [Extending Embedded Python](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html#extending-embedded-python):

> Until now, the embedded Python interpreter had no access to functionality from the application itself. The Python API allows this by extending the embedded interpreter. That is, **the embedded interpreter gets extended with routines provided by the application**.

Just read the docs I referenced and you should be able to implement Python interpreter within your app written in C.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a call from C++ to Python and vice versa using [Boost Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/)

Comment: This is great for writing C++ extensions to Python and enabling those extensions to participate sensibly in the inheritance hierarchy. But not so great for embedding Python in another application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested I recently implemented embedded Python scripting for C++ from first principles. I created a C++ Python wrapper library called ECS:Python (Embedded C++ Scripting with Python) that allows you to expose object from a C++ application to an embedded Python interpreter for interactive scripting. It's light-weight and very easy to use (and free!).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecspython